# Share google analytics report with clients

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, reportingservices-2005

I have many sites which I am doing Google analytics., now I need to display the analytics results in my website and it should be visible to all. I used google analytics api. But after authorization it shows the logged users analytics report..

Comment: check out this [Server side auth](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) example.

Comment: sounds like you are doing client-side authorization.  As @Matt says - you need to utilize server side oAuth.  If you have many sites that you want to report GA on, check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com - we specialize in GA reporting for agencies and CMS systems.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the client id in the Google Developer console I would assume that you created Oauth2 credentials.  This will allow your application to access the authenticated users Google analytics account.

If you want to show others your google analytics data you need to create a service account.  Once you have created the service account in Google developer console take the service account email address and add it as a user at the ACCOUNT level it must be the Account level in the admin section of the Google Analytics website.   The service account will then have access to the Google analytics data.  You will then be able to show the users your Google Analytics Data.

Oauth2 credentials are for accessing authenticated users data.   Service accounts are for accessing data you the developer own.